# Check that any directory exists inside given one

Tags: c#, .net, find, subdirectory

My application is Windows, C# 3.0. I want to make sure that a directory given does not contains subdirectories. Naive code like

```
if (Directory.GetDirectories(path).Length != 0)
```

will work very slow on directories which contain e.g. 10000 subdirectories, because it will build a list of subdirectories, while even 1 directory is already enough for me.

Is there a way in .NET to determine 1 subdirectory quickly?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Directory.EnumerateDirectories().Any())
```

`EnumerateDirectories` will return directories only as you enumerate the returned sequence (deferred execution).

Comment: Ooops, this is 4.0 method. It does not suit me unfortunately.

Comment: Search online; there may be code samples to do similar things in earlier versions.  You'd need to call the `FindFirstFile()` API method.

Comment: I can see the code of 3.0 GetDirectories - they are using Pinvoke as well, so probably I can take code from it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function overload this will only look for directories in the current directory, not the entire tree:

```
if (Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length != 0)
```

Comment: I am speaking about a directory with direct 10000 children.